# Analyzing oracle table with duplicate records

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am working on PL SQL developer 12 and i want to get the number of duplicate records in a given table. What is the best tool to use.

i have been trying to use the following `analyze table tablename compute statistics` but it is giving me a table doesnt exist error.

Please note that i am new in Oracle Database Development

Comment: first you have to know how to find duplicate records. Do you have a table that has duplicate records? Show us an example and I can write a query that will return duplicate records.

Comment: i am currently useing this code 'select columnname, count(columnname)
from tablename
group by columnname
having count (columnname) > 1;' but it is not bringing out the duplicates though when running the select * from tablename i can see duplicate records

Comment: i do have a table with duplicates um running on pl sql developer 12.

Comment: the SQL seems right, edit your question and add some sample data, soo we can figure it out

Comment: `select columnname, count(columnname) from tablename group by columnname having count (columnname) > 1;` Will give columnname and count  of its occurrence(duplicate rows). Why do you expect the result same as  `select * from tablename` . Ofcourse `select * from tablename ` will show all the records. And if you want to show distinct records use query `select distinct * from tablename`.

Comment: i have table with a column supplier_name and one supplier can have many policies so in this case i want a solution that can maintain the available data but removing repetitive supplier_name when calling the table record and also will it be possible to have a program that accepts only one supplier_name but being able to accept different policies totha same supplier_name

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Oracle world.

The statement you used `analyze table tablename compute statistics` will not help you. This command is used for computation of Oracle DB internal statistics, which are used by the query optimizer, so Oracle can find the best way how to query data (for more info refer to [Cost based Optimizer](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E98457_01/opera_5_6_core_help/cost_based_optimizer.htm)). Also this command is already deprecated and dbms_stats should be used instead [Analyzing Tables, Indexes, and Clusters](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general002.htm#ADMIN11524)

Now let's go down to your problem. It can be solved by having clause in your select. See example below:

```
create table foo_bar (
      id_foo integer generated by default on null as identity
    , name_bar varchar2(100)
    , constraint Foo_Bar_PK primary key (id_foo)
);

insert into foo_bar (name_bar) values ('John');
insert into foo_bar (name_bar) values ('John');
insert into foo_bar (name_bar) values ('Mike');
insert into foo_bar (name_bar) values ('Susan');
insert into foo_bar (name_bar) values ('Jerry');
insert into foo_bar (name_bar) values ('Jerry');
insert into foo_bar (name_bar) values ('Jerry');

-- query for all data
select * from foo_bar;

+--------+----------+
| ID_Foo | Name_bar |
+--------+----------+
|      1 | John     |
|      2 | John     |
|      3 | Mike     |
|      4 | Susan    |
|      5 | Jerry    |
|      6 | Jerry    |
|      7 | Jerry    |
+--------+----------+

-- this query will return all names which have more than 1 occurrence in the table
select name_bar
  from foo_bar
 group by name_bar
 having count(1)>1;

+----------+
| name_bar |
+----------+
| John     |
| Jerry    |
+----------+

--to get number of duplicate records you can use this
select sum(count(name_bar))
  from foo_bar
 group by name_bar
having count(1)>1;


drop table foo_bar;
```

Comment: i hear you. but this is my case i have table with a column supplier_name and one supplier can have many policies so in this case i want a solution that can maintain the available data but removing repetitive supplier_name when calling the table record and also will it be possible to have a program that accepts only one supplier_name but being able to accept different policies totha same supplier_name.

Comment: Could you describe more what you actually want to do? This description is quite confusing :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming duplicate records as in records having the same data for all the columns, following query might be helpful.

```
select column1, count(column1) 
from table1 
group by column1, column2, .. columnn
having count(1) > 1;
```

In the above query column1, column2, .. columnn are n columns (all columns) in the table.
Basically you have to group by all the columns and as you need only those records having duplicates you have the condition count(1) > 1